# How to fetch the unique value from Django-query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a method:

```
 def get_netmask(user=None):
     user = User.objects.get(username=user)
     id_user = user.id
     obj = Host.objects.get(user=id_user)
     obj = obj.ipv4_sub_net.distinct('ipv4_sub_net').order_by('ipv4_sub_net')

     # In this line i am getting an error: `'unicode' object has no
     # attribute 'distinct'` but the query is not complete . For full
     # question please follow the lines and given example

     return obj
```

Object of the Host model are `ipv4_sub_net` and `ipv6_sub_net`. My motive is for defining the above method is to get the value from  `ipv4_sub_net` + `ipv6_sub_net` model field which will be fetched from `Host model` corresponding to a requesting user (loginned user). To do this i passed `reuest.user.username` to the   `get_netmask` parameter at the time of calling it. Apart from that i also want to return the count os similar entry in `ipv4_sub_net` and `ipv6_sub_net` seperately.

For example:
In table there are four coloum present:

```
id      user_id        ipv4_sub_net       ipv6_sub_net
1       2              1.0.0.1             /23
2       2              8.9.7.3             /23
3       1              23.2.3.4            /43
4       2              1.0.0.1             /23
```

So, let's say that the requesting user is with `user_id` `2`. So according to method definitions it will return the dictionary. First index of dictionary contain unique `IPv4_sub_net + ipv6_sub_net` which is `"1.0.0.1"` and `/23` and the second index will return the count of returning similar `sub_net` for `ipv4 and the third index will return the count of similar`sub_net`for ipv6 which`2 for ipv4`and`2 for ipv6`.

Comment: what's the question? Please be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
obj = obj.ipv4_sub_net.distinct('ipv4_sub_net').order_by('ipv4_sub_net')
```

to

```
obj = obj.distinct('ipv4_sub_net').order_by('ipv4_sub_net')
```

**Edit**

On the first pass, I missed another error. You should also change

```
obj = Host.objects.get(user=id_user)
```

to

```
obj = Host.objects.filter(user=id_user)
```

`get` will always return a single object and throw an error if multiple objects are returned. If you're expecting a single object, then I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: it shows an error **'Host' object has no attribute 'distinct'**. *Host** is a model and ipv4_sub_net and ipv6_sub_net are two object of it. The error is so obvious but what will be the solution of that?